# Error while compiling clojurescript with om-tools.dom

Tags: clojurescript, om

Trying this Om & React tutorial https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/build-single-page-app-with-react-om-clojurescript . When compiling clojurescript I get an error `clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol at line 1  {:tag :cljs/analysis-error, :file nil, :line 1, :column 1}`.

Apparently the reason is in om-tools.dom. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

core.cljs:

```
(ns spa-tutorial.core

  (:require [om.core :as om :include-macros true]
            [om-tools.dom :as dom :include-macros true]
            [om-tools.core :refer-macros [defcomponent]]
            [secretary.core :as sec :include-macros true]
            [goog.events :as events]
            [goog.history.EventType :as EventType]))

(enable-console-print!)

(def app-state (atom {:text "Hello world!"}))

(om/root
  (fn [app owner]
    (reify om/IRender
      (render [_]
        (dom/h1 nil (:text app)))))
  app-state
  {:target (. js/document (getElementById "app"))})
```

project.clj:

```
(defproject spa-tutorial "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write this!"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2755"]
                 [org.clojure/core.async "0.1.346.0-17112a-alpha"]
                 [org.omcljs/om "0.8.8"]
                 [prismatic/om-tools "0.4.0"]
                 [http-kit "2.1.19"]
                 [secretary "1.2.3"]]
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.5"]]
  :source-paths ["src" "target/classes"]
  :clean-targets ["out/spa_tutorial" "out/spa_tutorial.js"]
  :cljsbuild {
    :builds [{:id "spa-tutorial"
              :source-paths ["src"]
              :compiler {
                :main spa-tutorial.core
                :output-to "out/spa_tutorial.js"
                :output-dir "out"
                :optimizations :none
                :verbose true}}]})
```

stacktrace:

```
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: failed compiling file:out/om_tools/dom.cljs {:file #<File out/om_tools/dom.cljs>}
at clojure.core$ex_info.invoke(core.clj:4403)
at cljs.compiler$compile_file.invoke(compiler.clj:1050)
at cljs.closure$compile_file.invoke(closure.clj:343)
at cljs.closure$eval3178$fn__3179.invoke(closure.clj:394)
at cljs.closure$eval3114$fn__3115$G__3105__3122.invoke(closure.clj:301)
at cljs.closure$compile_from_jar.invoke(closure.clj:386)
at cljs.closure$eval3173$fn__3174.invoke(closure.clj:400)
at cljs.closure$eval3114$fn__3115$G__3105__3122.invoke(closure.clj:301)
at cljs.closure$get_compiled_cljs.invoke(closure.clj:463)
at cljs.closure$cljs_dependencies.invoke(closure.clj:507)
at cljs.closure$add_dependencies.doInvoke(closure.clj:529)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
at cljs.closure$build.invoke(closure.clj:1081)
at cljs.closure$build.invoke(closure.clj:1020)
at cljsbuild.compiler$compile_cljs$fn__3416.invoke(compiler.clj:81)
at cljsbuild.compiler$compile_cljs.invoke(compiler.clj:80)
at cljsbuild.compiler$run_compiler.invoke(compiler.clj:180)
at user$eval3548$iter__3584__3588$fn__3589$fn__3607.invoke(form-init1935966926108010861.clj:1)
at user$eval3548$iter__3584__3588$fn__3589.invoke(form-init1935966926108010861.clj:1)
at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:40)
at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:49)
at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:484)
at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:133)
at clojure.core$dorun.invoke(core.clj:2855)
at clojure.core$doall.invoke(core.clj:2871)
at user$eval3548.invoke(form-init1935966926108010861.clj:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6693)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7086)
at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:274)
at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:279)
at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:307)
at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:342)
at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:420)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Don't know how to create ISeq 
from: clojure.lang.Symbol at line 1  {:tag :cljs/analysis-error, :file 
nil, :line 1, :column 1}
at clojure.core$ex_info.invoke(core.clj:4403)
at cljs.analyzer$error.invoke(analyzer.clj:299)
at cljs.analyzer$analyze_seq.invoke(analyzer.clj:1634)
at cljs.analyzer$analyze$fn__1802.invoke(analyzer.clj:1723)
at cljs.analyzer$analyze.invoke(analyzer.clj:1716)
at cljs.analyzer$parse_ns$fn__1819$fn__1824.invoke(analyzer.clj:1801)
at cljs.analyzer$parse_ns$fn__1819.invoke(analyzer.clj:1801)
at cljs.analyzer$parse_ns.invoke(analyzer.clj:1789)
at cljs.compiler$compile_file.invoke(compiler.clj:1032)
... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create 
ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol
```

Answer (score 0):

Clojure error messages (without clojure.spec) are an acquired taste. The message `Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol` means that ClojureScript is expecting a sequence (the `ISeq` interface), but it gets a `symbol`.

This is because the syntax of `:refer-macros true` is invalid for the compiler. You are using a newer version of Clojure to compile an old tutorial.

Nowadays ClojureScript expects a sequence of imported macros (e.g., `:refer-macros [first-macro second-macro]`), and not a boolean symbol (e.g., `:refer-macros true`). Although the latter [syntax was valid](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojurescript/FoiqNV5nunQ) in old versions of ClojureScript.

When you update your dependencies to newer version and you remove the `:refer-macro`s the code compiles. I.e.,

`project.clj`:

```
(defproject spa-tutorial "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write this!"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.9.473"]
                 [org.clojure/core.async "0.3.443"]
                 [org.omcljs/om "1.0.0-beta1"]
                 [prismatic/om-tools "0.4.0"]]
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.1.6"]]
  :source-paths ["src" "target/classes"]
  :clean-targets ["out/spa_tutorial" "out/spa_tutorial.js"]
  :cljsbuild {:builds [{:id "spa-tutorial"
                        :source-paths ["src"]
                        :compiler {:main spa-tutorial.core
                                   :output-to "out/spa_tutorial.js"
                                   :output-dir "out"
                                   :optimizations :none
                                   :verbose true}}]})
```

`core.cljs`:

```
(ns spa-tutorial.core
  (:require [om.core :as om]
            [om-tools.dom :as dom]
            [om-tools.core :refer-macros [defcomponent]]
            [goog.events :as events]
            [goog.history.EventType :as EventType]))

(enable-console-print!)

(def app-state (atom {:text "Hello world!"}))

(om/root
 (fn [app owner]
   (reify om/IRender
     (render [_]
       (dom/h1 nil (:text app)))))
 app-state
 {:target (. js/document (getElementById "app"))})
```

I would recommend switching to a newer tutorial that also uses [Figwheel](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel) (an awesome library that does hot code reloading in the browser). For example the [Basic Tutorial of the Om wiki](https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Basic-Tutorial).